# Why default copy constructor can receive undefined static member variable?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { std::cout << "Constructed" << std::endl; }
    // Comment 1.
    // Foo(const Foo& f) { std::cout << "Copy constructed." << std::endl; }
    void Miao() { std::cout << "Miao" << std::endl; }
};

class Bar {
public:
    static Foo f;
};

// Comment 2.
// Foo Bar::f;
Foo x(Bar::f);

int main() {
    x.Miao();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Miao
```

And if I attempt to overload the copy constructor of `Foo`(uncomment `Comment 1`), a compile error occurred:

```
/tmp/ccuF5B5q.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
default.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `Bar::f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My OS is ubuntu-14.04.5, and g++ version is 4.8.4.

I'm confused why this code works well?

Thanks in advance : p

Comment: Uncommenting the copy constructor doesn't cause an error for me: [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef0c6c585908fc94)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have added the compile error.

Comment: Does uncommenting Comment 2 help?

Comment: "Defined", not "initialised". (Though the definition does include an element of initialisation.)

Answer (score 3):

You did not provide a *definition* for `Bar::f`. As such, any *odr-use* of that object will result in a linker error. Your accepting a reference to it counts as that.

Either the implicit copy constructor does not count as *odr-use* or, more likely, because the implicit copy constructor is wholly invented by and owned by the compiler, it's more willing to optimise the copy away, so that your ODR violation is not diagnosed by the linker. Doesn't really matter either way.